# How to create complex table of contents using TCPDF?

Tags: php, tcpdf

I want to have 2 or more headings in one page. The headings should then be placed into the table of contents.

I want to achieve the result
[here](http://ivangasparetto.com/toc.pdf)

I tried everything in the [documentation](http://www.tcpdf.org/docs.php) and in the [examples](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php). The functionality doesn't seem to be there.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You probably must have missed example 45 on TCPDF website documentation.
[PDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_045.pdf) [PHP](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_045.phps)

Comment: I haven't. I don't think you tested before answering the question. 
http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_045.pdf#Sub-Paragraph%201.2.1 doesn't open the PDF at Sub-Paragraph 1.2.1

Comment: It did open on my Chrome. Which browser are you using ?